# Plants that don't need direct or indirect sunlight for air purification?

Tags: houseplants

I am looking for plants that can survive and grow with no sunlight(direct or indirect), which purifies air. I got some air purifiers but they need either direct or indirect sunlight. I have to get some more plants for air purification in the back room, a room which is on the back side where not a bit of sunlight comes. But so far I haven't found any plants.

Comment: Does the room get daylight, in other words, has it a window which allows daylight to enter, just not sun? Which plants have you got already?

Comment: All plants clean the air. The more light they have, the more vigorously they grow, the more air they clean. I had a peace lily in a corner that didn't get any direct light. Spent a couple weeks out of town with even all lights off and it was still fine when I got back. I posted some info on my blog which you might find useful. http://www.organiclawndiy.com/2015/03/cost-effective-air-cleaning-plants.html

Comment: Talk to the garden center where you buy plants, they can help you figure it out. There's too many plants that will do this, because "do you want flowering", "do you want food". . .?

Comment: @Bamboo There is light, but no sunshine. I got peace lilly and Aloe Vera.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY Thank you. I found many new plants and will see f they are available here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you will find any either. The very thing that makes a plant a plant is that it has chlorophyl which converts light and carbon dioxide into oxygen.

There are plants that can grow with little light such as Dracaena, Philodendron, Sansevieria and mosses but all plants require some form of light during there lifetime.

The only thing that grows without any light are fungi (mushrooms) and they use oxygen and output carbon dioxide just like us.

While you could use a grow-light, it is going to be less energy effective than proper ventilation or a an air purifier by an order of magnitude.

Comment: See [Plants Don’t Purify Air](http://www.gardenmyths.com/garden-myth-born-plants-dont-purify-air/)

Answer (score 2):

You say you have a peace lily already (Spathiphyllum) and that does not like direct sunlight, so that should work, along with Dracaena marginata and Sansevieria, common name Mother in laws tongue. There is a caveat though; all three will do better being placed close to the window, particularly in winter, and prefer an even temperature that doesn't get too cold, and without very dry air, some humidity is necessary. This might be difficult to achieve if there is a radiator or heat source under the window.